# Calling a function(on other db) from a view

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi I am trying to execute the following query, with no luck:

```
SELECT AA.Id, AA.ObjId, AA.NsId, AA.statusId, AA.LCID, AA.Title, AA.MessageBody_ClearText, AA.MessageBody_HTMLText, 
               AA.File1, AA.File2, AA.File3, AA.Status, AA.name, AA.createdate, AA.updatedate, AA.boneid, AA.main, AA.Sort, 
               BB.ID AS Expr1, BB.MainIDNum, BB.MessageID, BB.Message1, BB.Message2, BB.Message3, BB.MessageDate, 
               BB.AttachmentGUID1, BB.AttachmentGUID2, CC.MessageID AS Expr2, CC.Identification, CC.Viewed, CC.Deleted, CC.Id AS Expr3, 
               AA.FileName1, AA.FileName2, AA.FileName3
FROM  dbo.gnvw_ObjectsBones AS AA INNER JOIN
              --- XXX.dbo.MESSAGES AS BB ON BB.MessageID = AA.ObjId LEFT OUTER JOIN ---
               dbo.PersonalMessages AS CC ON CC.MessageID = BB.MessageID AND CC.Identification = BB.MainIDNum
```

The marked line need to be change to a function call, I have a function called 'GetMessages' that takes an 
int 'input' and it''s has to be that one: 'CC.Identification', so I tried to replace it to be like this:

```
SELECT AA.Id, AA.ObjId, AA.NsId, AA.statusId, AA.LCID, AA.Title, AA.MessageBody_ClearText, AA.MessageBody_HTMLText, 
               AA.File1, AA.File2, AA.File3, AA.Status, AA.name, AA.createdate, AA.updatedate, AA.boneid, AA.main, AA.Sort, 
               BB.ID AS Expr1, BB.MainIDNum, BB.MessageID, BB.Message1, BB.Message2, BB.Message3, BB.MessageDate, 
               BB.AttachmentGUID1, BB.AttachmentGUID2, CC.MessageID AS Expr2, CC.Identification, CC.Viewed, CC.Deleted, CC.Id AS Expr3, 
               AA.FileName1, AA.FileName2, AA.FileName3
FROM  dbo.gnvw_Data_PersonalMessages_ObjectsBones AS AA INNER JOIN
               XXX.dbo.GetMessages(CC.Identification) AS BB ON BB.MessageID = AA.ObjId LEFT OUTER JOIN
               dbo.PersonalMessages AS CC ON CC.MessageID = BB.MessageID AND CC.Identification = BB.MainIDNum
```

I also tried other solutions but none of them worked, Does somebody here see the problem? 
This is the errors that i get from running that 'solution':

'The multi-part identifier "CC.Identification" could not be bound.'

and,

'Invalid column name 'ID'.'
SQL is not my strong side, I'll be happy to hear any solutions, Hope I explained it right.

Comment: You're referencing `CC` before it's introduced in the `FROM` clause? In fact, you're somehow introducing a circular dependency - since the values for `CC.Identification` depend on the join conditions on `CC` - which are in part based on `BB` But now, to define `BB`, we need to know `CC.Identification`?

Answer (score 1):

When you need to join table-valued function , use `CROSS APPLY`/`OUTER APPLY` instead of `INNER`/`LEFT` joins respectively.

```
...
FROM  dbo.gnvw_Data_PersonalMessages_ObjectsBones AS AA 

CROSS APPLY XXX.dbo.GetMessages(CC.Identification) AS BB
....
WHERE BB.MessageID = AA.ObjID
```

**Update**
I just noticed that join condition for `dbo.AgamUsersPersonalMessages AS CC` refers only to `BB`, and join condition for `BB` depends only on `CC`. That's incorrect, and you will still get the error. Without knowing what you want to get, I cannot give you a solution; you need to figure out join conditions yourself...